# Getting audio device name for spotifyd

Tags: command-line, audio, spotify

I ran `aplay -l` and it returns:

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Pro [Razer BlackShark V2 Pro], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Now I am looking at the card 2 Razer headset, but I actually don't know what the name is, "Pro" does not exist so idk what to put in the config.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you not using pulseaudio and do you want the headset to be used exclusively by/for spotifyd though?

Comment: Well I cant figure out how to use pulseaudio, it just throws "unknown backend 'pulseaudio'", yeah I want to share my headset between spotifyd and netflix, games etc. I am really new to audio and spotifyd in linux

Comment: Better get a build with pulseaudio support. Otherwise you need to mess with alsa configuration and dmix. If you insist, see if you can find a dmix item for the headset already in `aplay -L` (yes captial L)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Z6raz19U <- Which one would that be?

Comment: You can try `dmix:CARD=Pro`, but it won't work very well / might not work at all. You'll might have to set a `FORMAT` explicitly and perhaps `RATE` (the options should be comma-separated), which depends on the capabilities of your headset and what you prefer. If you are lucky enough that what spotfiyd / any program outputs matches with the spec, it will work. But you probably need to use the `plug` plugin to "wrap" the whole thing for some stuff anyway. (I'm familiar with alsa conf'ing, neither do I want to go into that.)

Comment: `FORMAT=S16_LE` should be fine for most (if not all) devices. I think spotify(d) is at 44100Hz, so `RATE=44100` should work unless you headset can only take 48000Hz input. (In that case you can also try `RATE=48000` in case I'm wrong about spotifyd.)

Comment: Now it just throws:

Alsa error PCM open ALSA function 'snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate' failed with error 'EINVAL: Invalid argument'
Could not start audio: Alsa error: PCM open failed

Comment: You mean for both `RATE=44100` and `RATE=48000`?

Answer (score 0):

I got "pulse" as one of the devices when I call `aplay -L`. Once I used "pulse" for both "device" and "control" in spotifyd.conf file I got sound through bluetooth headset!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).